# Is this a generator of a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F=\mathbb Z/(p)$, where $p$  a prime number, $f(x)$ a monic irreducible polynomial in  $K=F[x]$ of degree $n$, $K=F[x]/(f(x))$, and $E$ the multiplicative group of nonzero elements of $K$. Then it is easy to see that $K=F(x+f(x))$. Is $x+(f(x))$ a generator of $E$ as a multiplicative group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the polynomial $f$.
If $x + (f(x))$ is a generator, $f$ is called *primitive*.
For each finite base field and each degree, a primitive polynomial always exists.

**Example**

There are 3 irreducible polynomials of degree 4 over $\Bbb F_2$:
$$x^4 + x + 1,\quad x^4 + x^3 + 1,\quad x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$$

The first two polynomials are primitive, but the third one is not.
This can be checked as follows:

In $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$, polynomial long division gives
$$
x^5 = (x + 1)\cdot(\underbrace{x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1}_{=0}) + 1 = 1\text{,}
$$
so $x + (f(x))$ has multiplicative order $5$. To generate the multiplicative group, its order must be $15$.

Comment: i want to know under what condictions , $x + (f(x))$ is a generator

Comment: @AiminXu You have to compute the multiplicative order of $x + (f(x))$, like I did above. Like for irreducibility, in general there is no "easier" way to check if a polynomial is primitive.

Comment: thanks a lot, a good example!